# LinearRegressionWithSGD() returns NaN

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark

I am trying to use LinearRegressionWithSGD on Million Song Data Set and my model returns NaN's as weights and 0.0 as the intercept. What might be the issue for the error ? I am using Spark 1.40 in standalone mode.

Sample data: http://www.filedropper.com/part-00000

Here is my full code:

// Import Dependencies

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
```

// Define RDD

```
val data =  
sc.textFile("/home/naveen/Projects/millionSong/YearPredictionMSD.txt")
```

// Convert to Labelled Point

```
def parsePoint (line: String): LabeledPoint = {
val x = line.split(",")
val head = x.head.toDouble
val tail = Vectors.dense(x.tail.map(x => x.toDouble))
return LabeledPoint(head,tail)
}
```

// Find Range

```
val parsedDataInit = data.map(x => parsePoint(x))
val onlyLabels = parsedDataInit.map(x => x.label)
val minYear = onlyLabels.min()
val maxYear = onlyLabels.max()
```

// Shift Labels

```
val parsedData = parsedDataInit.map(x => LabeledPoint(x.label-minYear   
,   x.features))
```

// Training, validation, and test sets

```
val splits = parsedData.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.1, 0.1), seed = 123)
val parsedTrainData = splits(0).cache()
val parsedValData = splits(1).cache()
val parsedTestData = splits(2).cache()

val nTrain = parsedTrainData.count()
val nVal = parsedValData.count()
val nTest = parsedTestData.count()
```

// RMSE

```
def squaredError(label: Double, prediction: Double): Double = {

return scala.math.pow(label - prediction,2)
}

def calcRMSE(labelsAndPreds: RDD[List[Double]]): Double = {
return scala.math.sqrt(labelsAndPreds.map(x =>    
           squaredError(x(0),x(1))).mean())
}
val numIterations = 100
val stepSize = 1.0
val regParam = 0.01
val regType = "L2"
val algorithm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
algorithm.optimizer
.setNumIterations(numIterations)
.setStepSize(stepSize) 
.setRegParam(regParam)
val model = algorithm.run(parsedTrainData)
```

Comment: give a sample of your data so we can reproduce the error

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with this specific implementation of SGD, but generally if a gradient descent solver goes to nan that means that the learning rate is too big. (in this case I think it is the `stepSize` variable).

Try to lower it by an order of magnitude each time until it starts to converge

Answer (score 0):

I can think there are two possibilities.

1. `stepSize` is big. You should try something like 0.01, 0.03, 0.1,
   0.3, 1.0, 3.0....
2. Your train data have NaN. If so, result will be likely NaN.